# WYSIWYG HTML Editor for Windows Mobile forms app

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, wysiwyg

I am developing a forms app (not web) for Windows Mobile, using .NET CF 3.5.  I need an HTML editor control.  I'm looking for something along the lines of a simple FCKEditor, but for using in a forms app (EXE).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pocket IE (the web browser included with Windows Mobile) is about as powerful as Netscape 2... without the Javascript support. So using a browser-based HTML editor isn't going to work with it. Opera has most of the power of the desktop version (including DOM and Javascript support), but I'm not sure it has an enbedding facility on Windows Mobile. Also it would mean your app would need a copy of Opera to work and it is commercial software.

I'd suggest you either: Scale back your plans somewhat and forget about WYSIWYG HTML editing. It's a small device with a small screen - is it really necessary for people to edit web content on it?

Or: You write your own small editor from scratch as a Windows.Forms control. If you only wanted to support font, size and color changing (which is 90%) of what people do in these editor boxes, it wouldn't be too hard, but it's still probably a few weeks work for an experienced .NET forms developer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is supported by the compact framework but you can try setting designmode on the WebBrowser control through reflection and wrapping it up to make a simple WYSIWYG editor.. think this is the code..

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetType().GetProperty("designmode").SetValue(webBrowser1.Document, true, null);
```

Answer (score -9):

About all I have that I can suggest is [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm).  I use it for Web stuff, but it has support for, I believe, 30+ languages, and it's free, so you may be able to find what you're looking for there.